# Laravel Api Resource with Relation and Elequent

Tags: laravel, api, eloquent, relation

we have a **model** "post" that every post **type** is **artist**, **song**, **album**
*artists* with song and albums have many to many relation
and every post get its title from eloquent with **meta Model**

we need return every posts (for example a song) with artists relation and their title(song title and artist title)
and this need in return single post (song) and a collection post (songs)

in PostController :

```
public function index()
    {
        return PostResource::collection(Post::with('artists')->with('title')->paginate(25));
    }
```

in PostResource :

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'slug' => $this->slug,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'artists' => $this->artists->title,
        ];
    }
```

Main Problem is artists of songs, when use `'title' => $this->title` it work for song(post type song) but when using `'artists' => $this->artists->title` its not work

**Thanks**

Comment: It's obvious that `'artists' => $this->artists->title` will not work, because `$this->artists` returns a collection not a single record.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-pluck) method to get a collection of titles from the collection of artists:

```
'artists' => $this->artists->pluck('title')->all(),
```

Comment: it's not working, title come from meta model that related to artist (post)